# Jquery Sizzle, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, magento

I have the following error in my Magento shop. Whenever the cart link is clicked I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://myshop.com/checkout/cart/
```

The error refers to a Sizzle function in the jQuery library and when jQuery is disabled the link works fine.
The link is called like any other link as followed:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
```

Even when I call it like this:

```
/checkout/cart
```

the link doesn't work

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to make the link work?

Comment: Is this Magento 1.9 (if not, what version)? What version of jQuery? Are you running other extensions that load their own jQuery as well?

Comment: It is indeed Magento 1.9. I'm using jQuery v 10.2.1min. Maybe does Bootstrap load its own jQuery?

Comment: Presumably you mean v1.10.2min? Hmm, that should be fine. Sounds like either a jQuery conflict or a 3rd party extension interfering with something. Are you using custom theme? If so, try rolling back to the default and see if you still have the unrecognized expression error.

Comment: Just encountered the issue on a site which is merging javascript with Google's mod_pagespeed. Solution to (hopefully) follow...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the link had the class "skip-link skip-cart"

Comment: It is meant to have those classes by default - I wouldn't expect those class names to be interfering with anything else on the site.

Comment: I would think so to, but when I removed the classes the link worked

Comment: It isn't the class names that are the problem but some jQuery somewhere that is trying to do something to those classes. By removing the class names, you are bypassing the loading of said problematic jQuery.